# Reload ngrx state data every time RouteGuard is activated

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, ngrx, ngrx-store

For the protected view of an entity I use a `RouteGuard` to preload the required data for the desired view into the ngrx store. However, the corresponding data from the backend can change over time. Therefore, each time the route is activated, the old state of the store should be overwritten with the new data from the backend, if there is any. The route should only be activated when the new data has been loaded into the store and is available at all. It could be that the entity has been deleted in the backend in the meantime.

For this I have the following minimal example: [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-demex2-7z8w8i)

In the current implementation the action `GetEntity()` is called every time the route is called, which loads the data from the backend. But the route is still activated based on the previous state of the store, which is not the desired behavior. The old state should be somehow invalidated or deleted to not be able to activate the route.
Here is the logic of the `canActivate` function of the `RouteGuard`:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.store.pipe(select(selectEntityMap)).pipe(
      map(taskMap => Object.keys(taskMap).length > 0),
      tap(loaded => {
        this.store.dispatch(GetEntity()); // trigger backend loading
      }),
      filter(loaded => !!loaded), // waiting until the enties has been loaded.
      take(1),
    );
  }
```

Therefore two questions:

1. **How can I change the RouteGuard so that it loads the data from the backend each time it is activated and only activates the route with the newly loaded data?**
2. **Is the RouteGuard the right place to implement this logic of reloading from the backend or are further adjustments to the state or effects necessary?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The way is to add flag when your guard starts that the data should be refreshed and emit only when it has been refreshed.

```js
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    // it should reset `taskMap` to undefined.
    // initial value of taskMap has to be null (anything but not undefined).
    this.store.dispatch(GetEntity());

    return this.store.pipe(select(selectEntityMap)).pipe(
      skipWhile(taskMap => taskMap !== undefined), // waiting until start
      skipWhile(taskMap => taskMap === undefined), // waiting until end

      take(1),
      map(taskMap => taskMap !== null),
    );
  }
```

2. right place is a resolver

```js
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserResolverService implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private fakeApi: FakeApiService) { }
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.fakeApi.getUsers().pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
      return empty();
      });
    );
  }
}
```

you can read more info here: https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-angular-route-resolvers-by-example

Comment: your first idea is not working properly since the RouteGuard is still activating the rule based on the old state. I tested this by removing the entity in the backend and reloading the page. The old state still has the deleted entity stored and is activating the route using the old state instead of the new state not containing an entity

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. I would vote for the loading flag. What is the initial state? can it be null for example? null - loading, an empty object / an object - loaded - like that?

Comment: isn`t using a resolver counter-inutuitive since my ngrx should be the single source of truth for my data?

Comment: in resolver you can dispatch store actions and resolve it as ngrx selectors.

Comment: the initial state is `null` and also can become `null` during the runtime. It can be like: null - loading - Object - null

Comment: I see, then we need a flag or to use `undefined` as value to indicate the loading. `skipWhile(value => value !== undefined), skipWhile(value => value === undefined)`. If initial state is null - and `GetEntity` sets it to undefined at the beginning - this should work.

Comment: The flag apporach seems to work. Is it possible to extend the flag apporach in the `canActivate` function to not only check if the loading is done but also check if the provided `entityMap` is defined? It can be possible to get null back from the backend as a result and store it in the store. To be more specific: return `false` if the loading is done but the entity is not defined and the route should not be activated because there is nothing to show.

Comment: I've updated the answer. if taskMap is null it returns false.